# Custom Operators in Swift

Tags: swift, compiler-construction, operator-keyword, language-design, operator-precedence

As we all know, one can define custom operators in Swift like this:

```
infix operator +- { associativity left precedence 140 }
```

The [Swift Programming Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID46) tells us about this that

> New operators are declared at a global level using the operator keyword

What I am wondering about this is what they mean by 'global level', and **how the Swift compiler figures out the operators at syntactical analysis**. Does the Swift compiler use a custom parser that requires to know these operator definitions at use site or does it have some special `OPERATOR_PRECEDENCE` compiler phase (or something like that)? Or something completely different that I am missing here?

Comment: "global level" simply means it that your custom operator must not exist inside of a class, function, struct, enum, or extension.  The most significant consequence of this is that operator functions can't hide other operator functions.

Comment: Ok, but which global level? At use site or at declaration site? Because if I had an external type defining an operator, the compiler needs to load the class first to know how to handle the operator, right? And I don't think a compiler can load types during syntactical analysis, where operator precedence is usually handled.

Comment: The Swift compiler figures it out. Have you tried putting it somewhere it didn't work? I don't understand what you are actually asking here.

Comment: I already guessed that the Swift compiler figures it out, but *how* does it do that? Note that the question is tagged [compiler-construction] for a reason... Just because you don't understand it doesn't mean it's a bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how swift does it, but it's not that difficult.

One approach is to first construct an AST in which an expressions is just a list of operands (including parenthesized subexpressions) and operators. Once the initial parse is complete and operators are declared, precedence (and fixity, if necessary) can be attached to each operator, and the AST is rescanned, rebuilding each expression list as an expression tree using a simplified form of the shunting-yard algorithm.

In the case of Swift, it appears that white-space is used to distinguish between prefix, postfix and infix operators (shades of Fortress!). It's not clear to me whether a sequence of operators would need to be rescanned once all operator names are known, but I can't see any other way of doing it since the whitespace rules do not allow a prefix operator (for example) to be followed by a space in order to separate it from a following prefix operator. That doesn't complicate the above algorithm much, since operators, operands and parentheses do not share any common characters. So even if it is not clear where every operator token starts, the worst that can happen is that you end up having to split an operator token into several actual operators.